# How to compare numpy multidimensional arrays difference?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, mean

Let's say I have two 1D arrays:

```
a = np.array ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 10])
np.mean (a! = b)
```

This would give as a result how much the two arrays differ from each other in %.
The same I'd like to do with multidimensional arrays, but taking a certain depth in account. E.g. We have two arrays with tuples.

```
a = np.array ([(1, 1), (2, 2)])
b = np.array ([(1, 1), (3, 3)])
np.mean (a! = b)
```

This would return 0.5 as expected. **My problem occures in the following scenario**:

```
a = np.array ([(1, 1), (2, 2)])
b = np.array ([(1, 1), (2, 3)])
np.mean (a! = b)
```

**This would return 0.25 and not as I would expect 0.5**. It seems numpy compares on the "deepest" level. Is there any way how can I influence the depth / axis, so that the result again would be 0.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to merge your diff-matrix in one dimension:

```
np.mean((a!=b).any(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach would be:

```
In [42]: a = np.array ([(1, 1), (2, 2)])
    ...: b = np.array ([(1, 1), (2, 3)])

# sum it along axis 1 and then take average
In [43]: np.mean(np.sum(np.not_equal(a, b), axis=1))
Out[43]: 0.5

# you can also, sum it along axis 0 and then take average
In [44]: np.mean(np.sum(np.not_equal(a, b), axis=0))
Out[44]: 0.5
```